# Nautilus sometimes spins and doesn't load everything in a dir (even a small dir)

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

I often find that when I browse around my local disk using nautilus, it will not display everything, and just shows a little spinner icon. This isn't just for large directories. Sometimes, even a folder with 2-3 files will cause it to behave like this (maybe show 2 files and spin permanently, instead of showing all 3).

If I just back up one directory and go back, it usually reloads immediately.

I sometimes worry it's that my disk is starting to have issues, but I've never seen any other tools (e.g. command line utilities like ls) hang on me like this.

Should I be worried about my disk, or is this just a bug in Nautilus? Perhaps there's a cache I can clear, or maybe even some indexer I can perma-kill, assuming it won't really hurt performance. I keep my display in "list" view, so it's not like it needs to read pictures to create large icons or anything.

EDIT(2021-07-17): Adding some data requested in comments:

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       5.1Gi        15Gi       164Mi        10Gi        25Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

SMART Data output:
[image: SMART output]

Comment: Something is wrong. Log into a different user account (create one if you need to) and see if the same problem occurs. Also show me `free -h` and screenshots of the `Disks` application's **SMART Data** window. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks! Updated post with the data - have not yet created the other user, will get to it a bit later. Things look pretty ok, though not sure what Data Address Mark Errors are.

Comment: While waiting for your results testing under a different user account, I created an initial answer for you to follow. Report back.

Comment: Not a hardware issue. It is a bug with nautilus I also experience now and then.

Comment: @vanadium If you have similar Nautilus problems, then your machine needs some kind of software repair also. If you like, start a new question with the details, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think this is likely, though. You would need to work on two different Del XPS machines. Of course, they both could be broken ;-) Nevertheless, I will follow up carefully here.

Comment: @heynnema I just learned that my file system was last checked on 20 oktober! It thus appears that nowadays, a system file system is not anymore automatically checked! So I am increasingly believing you are hitting the nail here!

Comment: @vanadium Check your /etc/fstab and make sure boot disk checks are enabled. Start a new question if you wish.

Comment: @user2671688 Status please...

Comment: @heynnema They are by default. Still, by default, a deep check is never done anymore because max mount count and max mount duration are both disabled. I find this default configuration a bit worrying.

Comment: @vanadium Where are you seeing these values? And what is meant by *"my file system was last checked on 20 oktober"*?

Comment: `sudo tune2fs -l <your partition>` indicates "Last checked:" date, and I tested and confirm that that is the last date of a *full* check (not just a quick check that the journal is clean: that action is not recorded).

Comment: @vanadium To continue this discussion, we should start a new question :-)

Comment: @vanadium Please see Update #1 in my answer. It may help you with your similar problem :-)

Comment: @heynnema I suspect this bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1887, which has just recently been filed over at Gnome for Files 40. The bug report indicates when it happens and includes steps to reproduce it, which I can perfectly. Despite it is for 40, I strongly suspect that that is the bug that I experience for years already. Glad I can pinpoint it better now.

Comment: @user2671688 Edit on previous comment: I cannot reproduce this on a (quite fresh) installation of 20.04. Please try the steps to reproduce the issue as indicated in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1887 on your system. Similar issue also raised here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359166/ubuntu-20-04-2-file-manager-doesnt-show-some-files

Comment: @vanadium Please review Update #1 in my answer. I had OP log into a different user account, and the problem couldn't be recreated... meaning the problem is specific to their normal login directory. I had outlined a number of possible suspect folders. Also, you can't recreate the problem on a fresh 20.04. But we haven't heard from OP since Aug 3, so I don't know if they tried any of Update #1.

Comment: @heynnema I am investigating right now, and indeed, it is related to having a big thumbnail cache. Wiping the cache causes the issue to disappear. I am about to put the cache back to see whether the problem reappears.

Answer (score 2):

We've proven that logging into a different user account solves the problem. This isolates the problem to something in your normal user account.

**Let's first check your file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Let's try and find out what's in your normal user directory that is causing the problem.

**Step #1:**

Next, let's try the quickest things first... in `terminal`...

- `cd ~/.config` # change to the .config hidden folder
- `mv nautilus nautilus.HOLD` # rename a folder
- Log out
- Log in
- Retry Nautilus
- If that doesn't fix the problem, you can always rename the folder back.

**Step #2:**

- `cd ~/.cache` # change to the .cache hidden folder
- `mv thumbnails thumbnails.HOLD` # rename a folder
- Log out
- Log in
- Retry Nautilus
- If that doesn't fix the problem, you can always rename the folder back.

**Step #3:**

If the first two quick fixes didn't help, we'll have to try something slightly more difficult.

There are three critical folders in your /home directory that can cause problems... .cache, .config, and .local.

We'll start with .cache...

- rename the .cache folder to .cache.HOLD
- IMMEDIATELY log out
- log in
- a new .cache folder got recreated at log in time
- see if the problem is resolved
- if it **is resolved**, then something in the .cache.HOLD folder was causing the problem

  - **move** items from .cache.HOLD folder back into the new .cache folder...
  - **BUT DO NOT REPLACE EXISTING ITEMS** in the new .cache folder.
- if it is **not resolved**, then the .cache.HOLD folder is not the culprit, and we need to put it back

  - to restore the original .cache folder...
  - rename .cache to .cache.NEW
  - rename .cache.HOLD to .cache
  - IMMEDIATELY log out
  - log in
  - move/delete the .cache.NEW folder
  - consult with me for the next steps... (.local, then .config)

Comment: Thanks, will do this after getting a backup tomorrow morning.

I assume, since I have all SSD, that I should only do the first step (fsck), and ignore anything under the "bad block" heading.

Comment: @user2671688 Correct. We don't bad block a SSD. I've removed that from my answer. Is your SSD really 5 years old? Have you tested under another user account yet?

Comment: Haha yes, my SSD is really that old. I got this system in 2014 sometime, and it's suited my needs nicely.

I've been having trouble reproing even on the current user. I *think* it might only happen for media files (the place I see it most consistently is with directories where I generate/update png files). If I just `cat /dev/urandom > <filename>`, in some dir, I cannot repro.

Comment: @user2671688 Status please...

Comment: life got in the way for a while, plus my external hard drive died, so need to get a new one to back up before doing this.

Comment: sorry to keep you waiting, finally got around to this. fsck didn't complain about anything. The first time I ran it, there were 5-6 "extent tree could be narrower", where I accepted the default option, and then it failed with "file system was modified", and then I reran, and it just output the 5 passes (rather quickly), and printed that it's 2.0% non-contiguous and the number of blocks.

Comment: @user2671688 The "extent tree" messages were errors, but the "file system was modified" is normal after fixing the previous errors. The non-contiguous message is ok too. Reboot, and see if the Nautilus problem returns.

Comment: It's still happening. This isn't happening with all folders, just ones where updates happen behind the scenes. For this specific case: I'm running a deepfake on the cloud, and I periodically download a training preview image using gsutil, which overwrites an existing png file with a new one. Then, when I go into that directory using nautilus, there's a chance it will flake out and I need to back out and re-enter. Due to the manner in which this repros, I'm more and more convinced that this a Nautilus bug, and not a filesystem issue.

Comment: @user2671688 Look for files with strange names, or that start with a . to make it hidden. You'll have to enable "Show Hidden Files" in Nautilus to see them. Are there a lot of files in these folders? If so, you may have to tweak a parameter for Nautilus to be able to handle the quantity.

Comment: @user2671688 Did you ever check if the problem occurs when logged into a different user account? I requested that on July 17.

Comment: There are no hidden files in those folders. The specific example I've been playing with currently has two files. Reproing with a different user would require duplicating quite a bit of setup. Can you provide both answers you'd give (one if I can reproduce with the other user, and one if I can't)? I've already tried clearing my ~/.cache/thumbnails, since I saw that recommended elsewhere. Is there any other local stuff that would look different/cleaner under a fresh user?

Comment: @user2671688 You don't need to create the exact circumstances that causes the problem. Just log into or create a new user, and try Nautilus on different folders, and see if you get the same problem. Report back.

Comment: Ok. I tried and I was not able to reproduce it.

Comment: @user2671688 Give me a minute to update my answer...

Comment: @user2671688 Status please...

Comment: @user2671688 Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Step #2 applies for me. Even more chirurgically: .cache/thumbnails is the culprit if it gets too large. There are 55221 files in my thumbnails/normal, and if only that folder is cleared, all is good.

Comment: It is not fixed, it is a workaround. You could also edit your answer to focus more on the specific cause - Step 1 should be deleted, in Step 2, only .cache/thumbnails needs deletion. Will upvote nevertheless ;)

Comment: @vanadium In your case, it is **fixed**. Having a .thumbnails folder(s) with 55221 thumbnails is an **abnormal** situation, and could only have gotten that large after years of system use. No wonder Nautilus was having problems. For other users the bad file/folder might be different. Deleting that folder is no more a workaround than tuning /swapfile size or tweaking vm.swappiness for a system-specific configuration. Anyway, I've updated my answer as per (some of) your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm convinced it is a bug that still exist as of March 2024.  I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 onto three different machines (Lenovo U430, T440, T470) (SSDs and CMR HDDs).  Nautilus does hang with "loading" displayed.  Fixed by backing out of folder and re-selecting folder.  All installations were clean installs on wiped drives, single user.  It is especially annoying when only one or two files are missing (and you don't see the loading message).