# Ubuntu 20.04.2 File manager doesn't show some files

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2. I'm editing some files from a CLI script that uses `exiftool`. It renames and changes some exif data of file. Sometimes, after script finishes, when I go into that folder on file manager that file won't show up and the folder loads forever. When I go to parent directory and come back, the file is there, everything is fine.

[image]

Any ideas on troubleshooting it further?
Thanks!

Comment: Also raised here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352467/nautilus-sometimes-spins-and-doesnt-load-everything-in-a-dir-even-a-small-dir?noredirect=1#comment2320845_1352467 I still see this nautilus bug in Files 40.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you write, i.e. leaving a folder, changing a file in that folder (`exiftool` in your case) and returning to see nautilus continuously "loading", coincides with a bug report, recently filed for Files 40 over at [Gnome Issues](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1887). Although reported for Files 40, I can reproduce the bug perfectly on 21.04 (Files 4.0). In my own experience, it is related to having a large thumbnail cache. Clearing the cache makes the issue go away, so constitutes a work around to this issue.

To clear the thumbnail cache, remove the `.cache/thumbnails` folder using the file manager or with the command:

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

This folder will be automatically recreated as soon as an application is creating thumbnails.